# ASP.NET MVC 4 project not recognized in Visual Studio 2017 RC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2017

I have an older ASP.NET MVC 4 project in our solution.  I just installed Visual Studio 2017 RC Community Edition (VisualStudio/public.d15rel/15.0.26020.0).  We have been using VS2015 successfully.

When I load the solution in VS2017RC, I get the error:

```
The application which this project type is based on was not found.
```

I've re-installed ASP.NET MVC 4 after installing VS2017RC, but it didn't help.

I plan to upgrade that to a newer version of ASP.NET MVC, but I'm hoping to use VS2017 in the mean time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RC is a "Release Candidate"; it may have known issues until the full release is ready. Your problem is one of them.

[MVC4 Projects are not supported](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes#KIWebTools)

You can keep up to date through the [release notes](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes).

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  My searches had "ASP.NET MVC 4".

Comment: @MikeJansen In VS 2017,How can we install MVC4 ?

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the .csproj file in a text editor
2. Find the code (may be different):
   `<ProjectTypeGuids> {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47}; {349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}; {fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc} </ProjectTypeGuids>`
3. Delete the section `{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};`
4. Save the file and re-open the solution.

Not all MVC4 attributes (f.e. Viewbag) are recognised in Views.
But at least you can open and run the project until a patch is released.

Comment: I encountered this problem in Visual Studio 2017 V15.4.0.  This fixed the issue for me

Comment: in my case i am using vs2019. I did same steps and worked, thx.

Answer (score 1):

They say it's fixed, pending release (at the moment).

Here's the UserVoice ticket: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2865/cannot-load-mvc4-web-project-in-vs-2017-rc.html